# Git Branch Bash Variable Shortcut

Tags: git, bash, unix

I am trying to create a bash variable which I can use to refer to my current branch in Git: something like $branch.

When adding: `branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)` into my `bash_profile`, I keep getting: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` when I start a new terminal.

Furthermore, `echo $branch` does not print out the branch name, as `git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD` would.

I'd like to be able to use it not to print out the branch name (I already have that in my prompt) but to do things like:

`git push origin $branch`

Comment: Don't you just want to use an `alias` you can call later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which branch you are on depends on which directory you are in.  If you have two git work trees, `~/a` and `~/b`, then typing `cd ~/a` can put you on one branch and typing `cd ~/b` can put you on another branch.

So trying to set `$branch` in your `.bash_profile` isn't going to work.  You need to update `$branch` every time you change work trees, and after any command that can change the branch of the current work tree.

The simplest thing to do is just *not* set a variable.  Instead, make an alias:

```
alias branch='git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD 2>/dev/null'
```

And then use it like this:

```
git push origin $(branch)
```

or like this if you're old-school:

```
git push origin `branch`
```

If you really want to set an environment variable, the simplest solution is to just set it every time you print your prompt:

```
_prompt_command () {
    export branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD 2>/dev/null)
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=_prompt_command
```

Note: you should check your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` to see if you're already setting `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  If so, just set `branch` in whatever function you're already running as your prompt command.