# get current branch name for use in git command

Tags: git

I sometimes want to use the current branch name to use in git commands. For example

```
git push origin feature/really-long-branch-name
```

**Is there a git command that will give just the branch name so I can do something like the following?**

```
git push origin current_branch
```

There is `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` but that's exactly useful in this case. Setting a default branch isn't that helpful either since the branch name changes often. Changing the default behavior of `git push` isn't what I'm looking for either since it still means having to type in the full branch name the first time I `push`.

Edit:

**Moderators**, this question is not a dupe so please do not close for that reason. Please read the bolded part of my question carefully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/git-push-current-branch

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - push current branch shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031970/git-push-current-branch-shortcut)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197548/git-branch-bash-variable-shortcut

Comment: Actually, since you already know how to get the name of the current branch, why *isn't* this a dupe of the other question? You can just set `git config push.default current`.

Comment: @CodeGnome changing `push.default` seems to only work AFTER an initial `push`. So the first time I still need to write the whole branch name.

Answer (score 23):

### Since June 2019, Use Built-In `--show-current` Flag

While this answer from 2013 has stood the test of time, Git learned a new git-branch flag back in 2019 that makes this much easier. In commit [3710f60a80](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3710f60a808ad79bfa604405a725e7accc64f743), git-branch learned a new flag for showing the current branch without requiring users to parse the list of branches or refs themselves. You can invoke it like so:

```
$ git branch --show-current
main
```

The other methods below continue to work, but this should now be the go-to solution for Git release versions >= v2.22.0.

### Read the Symbolic Ref of HEAD

There are a number of ways to get the name of the current branch. The most canonical is to read the symbolic ref for HEAD using [git-symbolic-ref(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref). For example, assuming you are on the *master* branch:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed 's!refs\/heads\/!!'
master
```

### Using the Ref

However you parse it, you can use the symbolic name in another command by invoking your shell's [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). For example, in Bash:

```
$ git log -n1 $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

There's no reason you couldn't use this trick with push or other commands, if you choose.

### Push.Default

If you're only interested in pushing the current branch to a remote branch with the same name, and aren't parsing the refs for some other reason, then you'd be better off using Git's *push.default* option described [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/1301972). For example:

```
git config push.default current
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` seems more straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I think git wont do what I want. So it looks like I'll need to write an alias to handle my use case.

Answer (score 5):

### Use HEAD

In the case of git push you can use HEAD.

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) states

> git push origin HEAD
>
> A handy way to push the current branch to the same name on the remote.

### Create an alias

For cases where you can't use HEAD I would create an alias for it. I am only familiar with the mac environment, this solution is for that platform but I am sure there are ways to do the same on Windows.

In your ~/.bash_profile create this alias

```
alias current_branch="git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
```

You can then use it in your git commands by doing

```
git push origin `current_branch`
```

Comment: Thanks this is really handy! I had never learned to use `` to substitute command output, usually my aliases worth without them but in this case it was needed so git pushes to the aliased branch rather than the alias name  :)